# Regular expression with some basic rules

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I want to create a regular expression that

```
1. Cant be empty
2. First character can only be a-z A-Z _ $
3. The rest of the string can only contain 0-9 a-z A-Z _ $
4. Maximum length of string is 5
```

My best effort is

```
^[A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]{1,5}$
```

But it doesn't work right when my string is and there can be other problems.

```
a
aaaaaa
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `{1,5}` -> `{0,4}`. Your regex is fine, just the limiting quantifier needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
^[A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]{0,5}$
```

Assuming you want 1-6 characters.

Or:

```
^[A-Za-z_$][A-Za-z0-9_$]{0,4}$
```

If you want 5.